# NetApp 7Mode, how to add AD group permission to a folder using .net API or NetApp CLI

Tags: netapp

I need to add a AD group to read/write access to the folder created inside the cifs shares.

I knew fsecurity will show the details like which are all AD groups have access to particular folder, but I want to write the details into netapp

please do the needful.

With Thanks & Regards
Amjath

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

you can add permissions with:

cifs access "sharename" "user,group" "rights"

For example:

```
cifs access finance COMPANY\FINANCE Full Controll
```

You can read about there:

https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196979/html/man1/na_cifs_access.1.html

For specific rights on a subfolder or file you have to do it on the filesystem.